# ¿Cómo enviar datos con AJAX de Jquery y recibirlos e imprimirlos en otra página PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Lo que quiero es enviar datos con `Ajax` a otro fichero donde se recibirán con `php` y se imprimirán en pantalla. Aparentemente he logrado con éxito enviar los datos (en la misma pagina desde donde envio los datos en la consola se muestran) pero al momento de recibirlos (en la otra pagina) y querer imprimirlos me dice lo siguiente: Notice: **Undefined** index: nombre. Pongo mi **código**:

```
//FICHERO ajax.php
<input type="text">
<button>PUSH</button>

<script>
$( 'button' ).click( function () {
  var dato = $( 'input[type=text]' ).val();

  $.ajax( {
    url : 'text_plain.php',
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'text',
    data : { nombre : dato },
    success : function ( contenido ) {
        console.log( contenido )
    }
  } )
} )
</script>

#FICHERO text_plain.php
<?php

echo $_POST["nombre"];
```

Comment: Ajax es justamente para hacer llamadas asincronicas en tu propia pagina, no para mandar datos a otra pagina. tal vez no estoy entendiendo algo, pero podrias explicar un poco mas que recibe la otra pagina?

Comment: La otra pagina recibe los datos enviados con ajax con el metodo POST. ¿Entonces quieres decir que AJAX ha sido hecho principalmente para recibir y no para enviar datos? Porque yo vi en un tutorial que si envian datos, pero a mi no me sale.

Comment: No no.. es doble via.. lo que me extraña es que hables de pagina.. sera una api y no nos estamos entendiendo? ojo, capaz soy yo que no te termino de entender...

Comment: A ver, por ejemplo con PHP lo normal es en la PAGINA 1 tener un form y enviar los datos a la PAGINA 2, donde se reciben con $_POST y se imprimen si asi lo quieres. Eso es lo que quiero hacer pero con AJAX. Por eso, en la PAGINA 1 tengo mi codigo ajax de envio, y pretendo recoger los datos en la PAGINA 2 con php..No se si asi se puede. Y si no, por favor muestrame un ejemplo correcto. Gracias.

Comment: AHHH... no.. yo no se como decirte que hagas eso, pero lo que si, AJAX no es para eso. AJAX llama a lo que vos quieras, pero no va a ir a esa pagina. No hace una redireccion, si no que llama a una funcion, con los parametros que vos queres, y recibe una respuesta. Se usa para hacer llamadas asincronicas. Por eso te preguntaba que era lo que querias hacer, y porque queres hacer con ajax. Lo que vos queres hacer, se hace como ya sabes hacerlo. Ajax es por ejemplo para llamar a un backend, que te va a devolver algo y procesarlo en la misma pagina.

Comment: Pero ¿y ese objeto que envié en la propiedad DATA de mi AJAX? ¿no es eso enviar datos?... Entonces estaba en lo cierto cuando te decia que Ajax es solo para recibir datos ¿?

Comment: Como dice @gabianchi, AJAX es utilizado para obtener una respuesta por parte del servidor(backend) esa respuesta por ejemplo en PHP es el `echo`, que pasa si mandas tu variable JS a PHP y al obtener esa respuesta haces un `window.location.href = 'PAGINA2.php'` te va a marcar `undefined` ya que lo estás redireccionando y se pierde la variable `$_POST[]`.

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es mas avanzado que AJAX, intenta hacerlo con socket.

Comment: No, ajax envia y recibe datos. Pero no va a otra pagina con datos. Habla con un endpoint (generalmente una api). Envia datos, y hasta puede no recibir nada (por ejemplo, si vas a hacer un delete, podria no interesarte si hay respuesta o no, solo hacerlo)

Comment: Cuentanos que es exactamente lo que queres hacer, para poder ponerte una respuesta que te explique el concepto. es otra pagina de tu web? es otra pagina de otro lado? cambias la pagina que esta mirando el usuario a esa otra pagina?

Comment: Mira yo ya sé hacer todo esto con PHP, pero me recomendaron aprender Ajax para mostrar datos en tiempo real sin recargar la pagina. Estoy en un tutorial donde me han enseñado a recibir los datos (esto lo entiendo perfecto), pero tambien hay un video que dice "envio de datos con ajax"..Eso me confunde. Pense que AJAX entonces era para enviar datos y recibirlos (al inicio tambien creia que podria escribir en un fichero con ajax, estilo php, pero ya veo que no). Les envio el link del video que me confunde, vean solo desde el minuto 1:45 a 2:25.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgC5iwlSd7A&t

Comment: y es lo que estas haciendo. Estas enviando datos, a un backend, no a otra pagina. Ajax no es para cambiar de pagina. Es para quedarte en tu pagina, y poder realizar cambios sobre la misma, pidiendo datos a algun lado (que muchas veces incluyen el envio de otros datos, por ejemplo si quisieras los paises de un continente, mandarias que contienente queres). No es que lo entendiste mal, capaz no lo explicaron claro. Recapitulando, AJAX es para **enviar** y **recibir** datos, pero no es para mandarlos a **otra pagina**, si no a un punto que devuelva algo.

Comment: Creo que ya entendi. AJAX me permite recibir datos de ficheros externos, pero tambien me permite enviar datos a ficheros externos, pero estos datos solo se pueden recoger en el mismo fichero desde donde se enviaron. Si intento recogerlos con PHP en el otro fichero me va a decir Undefined. Pero si los recojo en el fichero desde donde se enviaron, los datos se mostraran. Y la prueba de que si se han enviado es que, si en el fichero 2 no estableces un ECHO $_POST["nombre"] en el fichero1 no aparece contenido. O sea que en el fichero2 de todas formas debes llamar con POST al dato enviado con ajax.

Comment: Asi como lo veo, supongo que lo mejor será enviar datos con formularios a lo clásico, pero recibir con ajax. Porque el chiste de ajax es recibir datos  y mostrarlos sin recargar, lo que quiere decir que ajax fue hecho mas que todo para recibir y no para dar.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es como haría para recibir datos de una base de datos con ajax. Si hasta ahora veo que todos los datos recibidos se traen desde ficheros.Y por ultimo, preocupa el hecho de que google diga que los datos traidos con ajax no se indexan, no tienen valor para el SEO. Es como letras en una animacion Flash.Eso si es preocupante.

Answer (score 0):

intenta enviar texto...

primero crea el objeto

```
var miJson = {};

miJson.nombre = dato; //automaticamente crea una llave "nombre" con los datos

  $.ajax( {
url : 'text_plain.php',
type : 'post',
dataType : 'text',
data : JSON.stringify(miJson), //AQUI EL CAMBIO, usando JSON.stringify()
success : function ( contenido ) {
    console.log( contenido )
}
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que los datos que pasas por AJAX deben tener formato json es "nombre":valor por lo tanto creo que el problema es que te faltan una comillas en la variable nombre para que quede así

```
data:{"nombre":dato}
```

Comment: No, es igual, con comillas o sin ellas...las comillas son obligatorias solo cuando estas en un fichero con puro codigo json